# Can i upload build from new xcode 8 where my storyboard is created in xcode 6. Will apple approve it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am in a confusion. i have to upgrade my project but it was created in xcode 6. when i open it in xcode 8, everything is fine but it is showing an exception thatthe storyboard in build for older version. Can i use the same storyboard to get my app live or i have to create a new one.

Comment: More information is required - what is the exact exception? Does the app compile and run?

Answer (score -1):

My question to you is: Why didn't you upgrade before? I don't see any code so my answer to your question is "no" because of the error. If the error didn't exist then I suppose you can because Xcode isn't complaining. If it were me I would have upgraded the storyboard even if their were no errors in Xcode. I just think working with the latest version is easier and ultimately less fragile. If you could show the error in a screen capture that would be helpful along with code examples.

Comment: i am not having much time to do changes. on the other hand i want this to be live without rejection. the exception i am getting is .                This file is set to build for a version older than the deployment target. Functionality may be limited. Suggest please.